# Pyarrow Dataset: : Does predicate pushdown is applied when filter is applied non-partition colulmns

Tags: pyarrow

I have a dataset which is partitioned on `year` and `month` columns which are derived from a `date` column. Now, if I apply a filter on `date` column, would predicate push comes to picture - would Pyarrow engine able to understand that it could avoid reading unnecessary partitions when a filter on `date` column is applied. Or is that the predicate push applies only if filters contain partition columns ?

#### A dataset partitioned by year and month may look like on disk:

```
dataset_name/
  year=2023/
    month=01/
       data0.parquet
       data1.parquet
       ...
    month=02/
       data0.parquet
       data1.parquet
       ...
    month=03/
    ...
  year=2022/
    month=01/
    ...
  ...
```

#### Example Code

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

dataset = ds.dataset("parquet_dataset_partitioned", format="parquet",

                     partitioning="hive")
# does predicate push applies here ?
dataset.to_table(filter=ds.field("date") >= "2023-01-01").to_pandas()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but. Predicate pushdown uses partitioning and statistics. So filtering on `date` should be significantly faster than other fields, because the data is organized by `date`. However, filtering on a partition field is likely to be an order of magnitude faster still.

I recommend experimenting with `year`, `date`, and another field to measure the difference. On a similar dataset, I saw a ~4x speedup on the equivalent of `date`, but a ~50x speedup on `year`.